# When calculating the pressure increment when a capacitor is submerged underwater why do we take force as +dU/dx?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, capacitance

[image]

[image]

[image]

For the following question (working attached), the solution given has (k-1) instead of the (1-k) in the numerator of my answer. Can anyone elaborate on what I might be doing wrong in this question. Upon scouring the internet I found a similar method but with the force being taken as $F=+\frac{dU}{dx}$ instead of $-\frac{dU}{dx}$. So is my method wrong here and why? (an explanation of the +ve sign instead of -ve would be great)

Edit:
My strategy to solve the question was to consider the gap between the plates to be occupied by two dielectrics, one being water and the second being air. Taking their thickness to be x and (d-x) respectively. Then upon calculating the net capacitance, I calculated the potential energy of the system using $U=\frac{1}{2}C_{eq}V^2$. Then taking the force to be $-\frac{dU}{dx}$, I found out the pressure by dividing the expression by Area and replacing x in the answer with d as the capacitor will be fully submerged at the end.

My problem with the solution is that the answer comes out only if we take $F=+\frac{dU}{dx}$ instead of $-\frac{dU}{dx}$. Can someone pls elaborate on this.

Comment: Please write the question, your solution strategy, and your efforts in text and MathJax markup language. This is a reasonable request when you're asking for free help. Images can't be searched or read aloud, and random blotches of someone else's handwriting are hard to interpret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating the pressure from the derivative
of the energy with respect to the water height $x$, holding
the voltage $V$ constant. This is not the correct change
in energy. When you change $x$ holding $V$ constant,
the charge on the capacitor plates changes. At constant
$V$ this extra charge is supplied by your voltage source,
say a battery. You must subtract the energy from the addition of this charge off if you want
to calculate the energy change of the internal system. Alternatively, you can keep
the charge constant. That is change the voltage to $V$,
then disconnect the battery, and calculate the change in
energy with $x$.

Writing the energy as
\begin{equation}
U = \frac{1}{2}\frac{Q^2}{C(x)} = \frac{1}{2} C(x) V^2
\end{equation}
You can either calculate
\begin{equation}
-\left . \frac{\partial U}{\partial x}\right |_Q =
\frac{1}{2} \frac{C'(x)}{C^2(x} Q^2 = \frac{1}{2} C'(x) V^2
\end{equation}
where $\frac{d}{dx} C(x) \equiv C'(x)$,
or subtract off the battery energy (also known as
Legendre transforming to get the free energy)
\begin{equation}
F(V) = U-QV = -\frac{1}{2}C(x) V^2
\end{equation}
and then calculate
\begin{equation}
- \left . \frac{\partial F(V)}{\partial x}\right |_V
= \frac{1}{2}C'(x)V^2
\end{equation}